# Unable to resolve path to module in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2, module, eslint

I am facing **Unable to resolve path to module** in VueJS
when i have import SidebarContent.vue file this error has showing
This is my error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERffz.png)

This is my code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxpLi.png)

Comment: Please Quick Answer

Comment: The imported component is not located in the same folder. You need to use the correct structure.

Comment: Yes, My sidebar component is another folder and table folder is on another folder. How we link that

Comment: I have no clue on your folder/file structures. U just point to the right folder where your SidebarContent.vue is in.

Comment: Please, do not use images but copy/paste the exception and code into code blocks. This is way more readable and can be indexed by StackOverflow's search engine.